# Output DataTable XML in UTF8 rather than UTF16

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, utf-8, datatable

I have a DataTable that I'm creating an XML file from using .WriteXML(..), although I have a problem with it exporting in UTF-16 encoding and there seems to be no apparent way of changing this.  I understand that .NET uses UTF-16 internally within strings, is this correct?

I'm then running the XML that DataTable.WriteXML() produces through an XSLT that includes the following in the output declaration:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
```

But still, the output from the transformation is in UTF16, and the system I am trying to input this XML file into doesn't support UTF16.

Is there any way to force the output to UTF-8?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The encoding of the result-document is determined by the `encoding` attribute of the `<xsl:output>` instruction** -- not by the XML declaration of the XML document that contains the XSLT transformation.

Here is an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <t>Hello, world!</t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used in this simple demo), the result wanted is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><t>Hello, world!</t>
```

**Do note**: In .NET you might need to specify particular settings of the XmlWriter passed as parameter to the `XslCompiledTransform.Transform()` method. See **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.encoding.aspx)** for details how to specify the wanted encoding in the `XmlWriterSettings` class.