# Prevent XSLT transform from converting utf-8 XML into utf-16?

Tags: delphi, xslt, utf-8, delphi-xe2, utf-16

In Delphi XE2, I'm doing a xslt transform on a received XML file to remove all namespace information.
Problem: It changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

This is the XML that I get back from Exchange server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="0" MajorBuildNumber="722" MinorBuildNumber="0" Version="Exchange2010" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<m:ResolveNamesResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<m:ResponseMessages>
<m:ResolveNamesResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
<m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
<m:ResolutionSet TotalItemsInView="1" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
<t:Resolution>
<t:Mailbox>
<t:Name>developer</t:Name>
<t:EmailAddress>developer@timetellbv.nl</t:EmailAddress>
<t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
<t:MailboxType>Mailbox</t:MailboxType>
</t:Mailbox>
<t:Contact>
<t:Culture>nl-NL</t:Culture>
<t:DisplayName>developer</t:DisplayName>
<t:GivenName>developer</t:GivenName>
<t:EmailAddresses>
<t:Entry Key="EmailAddress1">SMTP:developer@timetellbv.nl</t:Entry>
</t:EmailAddresses>
<t:ContactSource>ActiveDirectory</t:ContactSource>
</t:Contact>
</t:Resolution>
</m:ResolutionSet>
</m:ResolveNamesResponseMessage>
</m:ResponseMessages>
</m:ResolveNamesResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is the function that removes the namespace info:

```delphi
Uses
   MSXML2_TLB; // IXMLDOMdocument

class function TXMLHelper.RemoveNameSpaces(XMLString: String): String;
const
  // An XSLT script for removing the namespaces from any document.
  // From http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Remove-Namespaces.xsl
  cRemoveNSTransform =
    '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">' +
    '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>' +

    '<xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">' +
    '    <xsl:copy>' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates/>' +
    '    </xsl:copy>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="*">' +
    '    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>' +
    '    </xsl:element>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '<xsl:template match="@*">' +
    '    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">' +
    '      <xsl:value-of select="."/>' +
    '    </xsl:attribute>' +
    '</xsl:template>' +

    '</xsl:stylesheet>';

var
  Doc, XSL: IXMLDOMdocument2;
begin
  Doc := ComsDOMDocument.Create;
  Doc.ASync := false;
  XSL := ComsDOMDocument.Create;
  XSL.ASync := false;
  try
     Doc.loadXML(XMLString);
     XSL.loadXML(cRemoveNSTransform);
     Result := Doc.TransFormNode(XSL);
  except
     on E:Exception do Result := E.Message;
  end;
end; { RemoveNameSpaces }
```

But after this, it's suddenly a utf-16 document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Envelope>
[snip]
</Envelope>
```

After Googling "xsl utf-8 utf-16" I tried several things:

- Change the line (e.g. [Output DataTable XML in UTF8 rather than UTF16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476883/output-datatable-xml-in-utf8-rather-than-utf16))

  ```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no">
  ```

  into either:

  ```
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:output encoding="utf-8"/>
  ```

  That did not work.
  (It would be the optimal solution, according to http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/09/04/xslt.html "The encoding attribute actually does more than add an encoding declaration to the result document; it tells the XSLT processor to write out the result using that encoding.")
- Change the line (e.g. [XslCompiledTransform uses UTF-16 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302858/xslcompiledtransform-uses-utf-16-encoding))

  ```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  ```

  into

  ```
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />
  ```

  which leaves out the starting xml tag, but if I then just prepend

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  ```

  I will lose characters because no actual utf conversion is done.
- IXMLDOMdocument2 does not have an `Encoding` property

Any ideas how to fix this?

Remarks/background:

- If all else fails there's maybe still the option to change the utf-16 XML data to utf-8, but that's an entirely different approach.
- I'm trying to do everything utf-8 because I'm communicating with Exchange server through EWS, and setting the http request header to utf-16 does not work: Exchange tells me that the content-type 'text/xml; charset = utf-16' is not the expected type 'text/xml; charset = utf-8'. EWS returns utf-8 (see start of post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use IXMLDocument in you original code, it should look like this:

```
var
  iInp, iOtp, iXsl: IXMLDocument;
  Utf8: UTF8String;
begin
  iInp := LoadXMLData(XMLString);
  iXsl := LoadXMLData(cRemoveNSTransfrom);
  iOtp := NewXMLDocument;
  iInp.Node.TransformNode(iXsl.Node,iOtp);
  iOtp.SaveToXML(Utf8);
end
```

Now the variable Utf8 should contain transformed XML in UTF-8 encoding, If you want save to stream/file, replace SaveToXML by

```
  iOtp.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
  iOtp.SaveToFile(....);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the use of the `transformNode` method, it returns a string and with MSXML such a string is UTF-16 encoded. So you need to create an empty MSXML DOM document for the result and use [the `transformNodeToObject` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing the empty DOM document as the second argument, then you can save the result document to a file or stream and the encoding should be as specified in the `xsl:output` directive.

Comment: I'd say that DOM is internaly implemented using UTF-16 hence the result of transformation in target DOM document will be encoded in UTF-16 as well. Encoding per se should be a task for input/output filter, so I'd expected it is neccessary to call e.g. `iXMLDocument.SaveToXML(AUTF8String)`

Comment: MSXML does not have a method named `SaveToXML`. It has a method named `save` on DOM documents and my suggestion is to use that method on a DOM document that was created empty and then passed in to the `transformNodeToObject` method. That way, if you save to a file or stream, the encoding should be as intended. That is not possible if you use `transformNode`.

Comment: I know. I used to do not call MSXML directly but via `IXMLDocument`/`IXMLNode`. There are overloaded methods `TransformNode` and one of them calls `transformNodeToObject`. My comment has concerned neccessity to perform some kind of **save** operation to ensure proper encoding. It can be saved easily e.g. by calling SaveToXML and passing var argument of type UTF8String.

Comment: I prefer the IXMLDocument approach, (OLEVariants tell nothing about types and methods, no code completion possible etc). 
I'm trying var Doc, XSL, Res: IXMLDocument; TopNode : IXMlNode;
  Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil); Doc.Active := true;
  XSL := TXMLDocument.Create(nil); XSL.Active := true;
  Res := TXMLDocument.Create(nil); Res.Active := true;
  TopNode := Doc.documentElement;
  Doc.XML.Text := XMLString;
  XSL.XML.Text := cRemoveNSTransform;
  TopNode.TransformNode(XSL.DocumentElement,Res);  
  Result := Res.XML.Text;
  
but get 'No active document' on TransformNode. What's wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve by assigning to ` Doc.XML.Text` or `XSL.XML.Text`. Use `loadXML(string)` to parse some string with XML/XSLT markup into a DOM document. And what exactly is it you want to achieve, what kind of result are you looking for? If you need a file with the transformation result I strongly suggest you let MSXML create that by calling `Res.Save("result.xml")`. If you don't want a file with the transformation result but merely a string them I am not sure the attempt with `transformNodeToObject` helps, the `xml` property of a DOM document is too an UTF-16 enc. string